# Binding to LDAP service

Tags: ruby, ldap

I'm using Ruby and trying to bind an LDAP server. The Ruby documentation seems to be very vague here and it's not obvious what I need to do after the following:

```
>> require 'uri'
=> true

>> newuri = URI::LDAP.build({:host => '10.1.1.1', :dc => 'cjndemo' , :dc => 'com',       :user =>'admin', :password => 'Passw0rd'})
=> #<URI::LDAP:0x007fea9d0cef60 URL:ldap://10.1.1.1?>
```

What do I need to do to bind then query my LDAP service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URI::LDAP is only for parsing and generating LDAP URIs. If you want to query the LDAP server you need to use a different tool like [net-ldap](https://github.com/RoryO/ruby-net-ldap) or [ruby-ldap](https://github.com/alexey-chebotar/ruby-ldap).

An example of binding with simple authentication using net-ldap:

```
require 'net/ldap'

ldap = Net::LDAP.new(:host => '10.1.1.1',
                     :auth => {
                       :method => :simple,
                       :username => 'cn=admin,dc=cjndemo,dc=com',
                       :password => 'Passw0rd'
                      })

if ldap.bind
  base = 'dc=cjndemo,dc=com'
  filter = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq('objectclass', '*')
  ldap.search(:base => base, :filter => filter) do |object|
    puts "dn: #{object.dn}"
  end
else
  # authentication error
end
```

Comment: Arr - I see. Is there much difference between these two libraries?